# Why do I get the error "java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.List" with the following snippet?

Tags: java, json, string, arraylist, classcastexception

Here is a sample snippet where I am trying to get array list from a json object by I am getting class cast exception while doing this.

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    List<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    arrayList.add("a");
    arrayList.add("b");
    arrayList.add("c");
    arrayList.add("d");
    arrayList.add("e");
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    json.put("raja", "suba");
    json.put("arraylist", arrayList);
    System.out.println("Thus the value of array list is : "+json.get("arraylist"));
    List<String> oldlist = (List<String>) json.get("arraylist");
    System.out.println("Old list contains : "+oldlist);
    System.out.println("The old json contains : "+json.toString());
    String result = json.toString();
    JSONObject json1 = new JSONObject(result);
    System.out.println("The new json value is  : " +json1);
    System.out.println("The value in json for raja is  :" +json1.get("raja"));
    System.out.println("The vlaue of array list is  : "+json1.get("arraylist"));
    List<String> newlist = (List<String>) json1.get("arraylist");
    System.out.println("Thus the value of new list contains : "+newlist);
}
```

I am not getting exception while obtaining `oldlist` but I'm getting class cast exception while obtaining `newlist`.

1. Why the array list is treated as an object in the first case but as a string in the second case?
2. What json.toString() really does? Does it converts the entire json object to string like appending double quotes "" to entire json object or does it converts each and every object within it into string?

Comment: You will have to find a way to tell `json` the type of value against key `arraylist`.

Comment: you are saying like we should get the array list like "getString", "getLong" something like this... is that so @santosh-patil?

Comment: If your instension is to get the list from the jsonobject then use the following code:
        JSONArray oldlist = json.getJSONArray("arraylist");
        System.out.println("Old list contains : " + oldlist);

Comment: Since array list is not a JSONArray - trying to obtain it as json array would again cause error..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that when you do

```
json.put("arraylist", arrayList);
```

you are explicitly asking for a list serialization. This means that underlying logic will be performed in order to save class-related metadata into the JSONObject. When you do json.toString(), though, this metadata are lost and you end up with a old plain String object. Then, when you try to deserialize this String at runtime, you get a ClassCastException because it doesn't really know how to convert that String into a list.

To answer your second question, JSONObject.toString() returns a String representation of an object in JSON format. This means that if you have an ArrayList, instead of having a field with the ArrayList.toString() value, you will have an array element with the list values.

Comment: Thanks for your reponse @Aurasphere. I couldn't get your point here "you are explicitly asking for a list serialization. This means that underlying logic will be performed in order to save class-related metadata into the JSONObject". Can you please explain me more on this?

Comment: I am not getting the point - what meta data related to the class would be saved here - how it would help in serialization and deserialization?

Comment: Sure. When you serialize a class, whatever format you use (XML, JSON...) you basically take a java object and transform it into a String. When you do the reverse, you take this String and transform it back into an instance of an object. The point is: how does your deserializer class know what class to pick for your JSON fields? When your JSON is itself a Java object (the case of your JSONObject) you can store this info into the Java object. But where would you store it into a String? Some frameworks like Google's GSON can do that but it's not built-in into JSONObject.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Aurasphere. You have explained it very clearly - helps me understand my problem :-)

Comment: That's nice to hear! :D